# SQL Return different values on the same row, based on a value thats in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having a very difficult time trying to get my result to display they i need them to display... here and example of what my query looks like and below will be the result i need...
 iv been at this for a long time trying case statements and joins but have had no luck, if anybody can help i would really appreciate it.

```
table name dbo.DTLPAYMENTS 

columns   
PTNO    
CD   
AMT   
DESCRIPTION
```

my query displays my result back to me like so...also there never an equal amount line for credits and debits. so a person can have more debits(>0) than credits(<0) and vice versa....

```
PTNO       /  CD    / AMT   / DESCRIPTION    
10007558931 30073   688.82    PAYMENT-ME    
10007558931 30073   -704.44   PAYMENT-ME    
10007558931 30073   704.44    PAYMENT-ME    
10007558931 30073   -688.82   PAYMENT-ME    
10007558931 30073   -698.82   PAYMENT-ME
```

i need this the debit and credit in separate columns
if there any way possible i can have it result back to me like so...

```
PTNO /      CD /    AMT /   DESCRIPTION / CD /     AMT / DESCRIPTION    
10007558931 30073   688.82  PAYMENT-ME    30073   -688.82  PAYMENT-ME   
10007558931 30073   704.44  PAYMENT-ME    30073   -698.82  PAYMENT-ME   
10007558931                               30073   -704.44  PAYMENT-ME
```

and thanks you if anyone can help me

Comment: please put you code in code blocks so that people can read it easily.

Comment: How does one distinguish Debits from Credits? Positive transaction = Credit, Negative transaction = Debit?

Comment: yea sorry first time posting. trying to get use to everything. but the Positive transaction = Debit and the Negative transaction = Credit sorry again

Comment: According to your sample output, you don't necessarily want identical AMT values on the same row? You just want them chronologically aligned in two columns?

Comment: Its not clear how are two rows differ in the output ?

Comment: What's the primary key / unique id on your table? How do you want to determine the order in which the results appear? Is this Microsoft SQLServer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use CTEs to separate Credits and Debits into separate data sets, then FULL JOIN them based on PTNO, CD, and inverse value (* -1) of AMT.

Edit: Since joining based on AMT is not a goal, I used BatchSeqID as a way to sort the data chronologically. Using a ROW_NUMBER() to order the two data sets, I then joined then on this value.

```
;WITH
Credit AS
(   SELECT PTNO,CD,AMT,DESCRIPTION,
    ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY PTNO,CD ORDER BY BatchSeqID) AS Sort
    FROM dbo.DTLPAYMENTS
    WHERE AMT < 0 ),
Debit AS
(   SELECT PTNO,CD,AMT,DESCRIPTION,
    ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY PTNO,CD ORDER BY BatchSeqID) AS Sort
    FROM dbo.DTLPAYMENTS
    WHERE AMT > 0 )

SELECT  ISNULL(c.PTNO,d.PTNO) AS PTNO,
        ISNULL(c.CD,d.CD) AS CD,
        --Credit data
        c.AMT AS CRAMT,
        c.DESCRIPTION AS CRDESCRIPTION,
        --Debit data
        d.AMT AS DBTAMT,
        d.DESCRIPTION AS DBTDESCRIPTION
FROM Credit c
FULL JOIN Debit d 
    ON d.PTNO = c.PTNO
    AND d.CD = c.CD
    AND d.Sort= c.Sort
```

Comment: There also a BatchNo And BatchSeqID Column in the table which are unique for each transaction would i just add that to the top select statements to prevent dups?

Comment: Is BatchNo unique to debit/credit pairs, and BatchSeqID unique to each credit or debit?

Comment: BatchNo is not unique to debit/credit pairs. The batchseqid is unique to every credit and debit there never the same for any transaction.

Comment: Without a way to pair Credits and Debits, it will be arbitrary. But assuming BatchSeqID is relatively chronological in order, I can use that to put each column in chronological order. Editing answer.

Comment: Answer edited. This solution will sort each data set (credit columns, debit columns) by the BatchSeqID, and eliminates the prior issue with duplication in the event of identical transaction AMT values.

Comment: What the PARTITION BY doing? I always i have a hard time understanding it. But the query looks good i've been testing it and everything seems perfect so far

Comment: The PARTITION BY clause indicates how the numbering is grouped. For each unique combination of PTNO and CD, the counting restarts at 1.

Comment: awesome thanks. so far the results seem perfect. One last thing if i wanted to add a column for zero transaction would that possible as well? I created the top portion i just dont see how i could link it in the from/ full join. The zero transaction is in the same table as the other two. so if it could do the same thing that would be great if not no worrys. what youve done so far has been a big help

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem. Just create a third identical CTE (perhaps called Zero) with the clause WHERE AMT = 0, FULL JOIN it just like the existing join, change the 2 ISNULL to COALESCE and add values from Zero to the clauses, and append z.AMT and z.Desc to your SELECT. I think that should do it!

Comment: Be sure to click the "Accept" button if you're satisfied with the solution!

Comment: Should be a Check icon underneath the vote count at the top of the response. http://stackoverflow.com/about

Comment: is there anyway to use a while loop to go through multiple databases with this CTE? i pasted my code below that i normally use to loop through databases if that helps explain what im trying to acheieve

Answer (score 0):

if you don't like Matt's solution and the risk of duplicated rows, you can have every transaction on a different row:

```
SELECT PTNO,
       CASE WHEN AMT < 0 THEN cd ELSE null END DBTCD,
       CASE WHEN AMT < 0 THEN amt ELSE null END AMTCD,
       CASE WHEN AMT < 0 THEN DESCRIPTION ELSE null END DBTDESCRIPTION,
       CASE WHEN AMT > 0 THEN cd ELSE null END CRCD,
       CASE WHEN AMT > 0 THEN amt ELSE null END CRAMT,
       CASE WHEN AMT > 0 THEN DESCRIPTION ELSE null END CRDESCRIPTION
FROM TABLE1
order by PTNO, AMT
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c54c4/14) you can see and play wiht the result.

```
 PTNO           DBTCD   AMTCD   DBTDESCRIPTION  CRCD    CRAMT   CRDESCRIPTION
 10007558931    30073   -704    PAYMENT-ME      (null)  (null)  (null)
 10007558931    30073   -699    PAYMENT-ME      (null)  (null)  (null)
 10007558931    30073   -689    PAYMENT-ME      (null)  (null)  (null)
 10007558931    (null)  (null)  (null)          30073   689     PAYMENT-ME
 10007558931    (null)  (null)  (null)          30073   704     PAYMENT-ME
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to sort the output on the magnitude of the `amt` column, try:

```
select ptno,
       max(case sign(amt) when 1 then cd end) dr_cd,
       max(case sign(amt) when 1 then amt end) dr_amt,
       max(case sign(amt) when 1 then description end) dr_desc,
       max(case sign(amt) when -1 then cd end) cr_cd,
       max(case sign(amt) when -1 then amt end) cr_amt,
       max(case sign(amt) when -1 then description end) cr_desc
from (select d.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by ptno, cd, sign(amt) 
                                order by abs(amt)) rn
      from DTLPAYMENTS d) sq
group by ptno, cd, rn
order by ptno, cd, rn
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ac809/7).